# Superman and the range of red kryptonite

Tags: dc, superman, kryptonite

Is it documented on the range of kryptonite? In particular, how close does red kryptonite have to be before it has an affect on Superman?

Comment: It depends. I mean, in what canon?

Comment: This inspires me to wonder if kryptonite has ever been shot from a cannon...

Comment: @Verdan  - I don't think so. From a gun, loads of times but I can't recall a cannon

Comment: http://www.majorspoilers.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/actoincomicsannual10/actioncomicsannual10-6.jpg - Green Kryptonite = 10 feet. - http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Annual_Vol_1_10

Comment: Its supposedly the case that kryptonite affects superman due to its radiation emissions (hence why it can be blocked by lead.) this would mean that it effects him based on the inverse square of the distance and the amount of kryptonite emissions. this means that the answer is probably much muddier than a simple range, hence why the writers can do what they want and not need to worry about any concrete rules.

Comment: Not a cannon, but a catapult is, er, canon.  http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superboy_Vol_1_125

Comment: Just to comment on this, I remember a DC comic that you could buy in the UK in the summer 1966. It had a centre page with a chart showing all the colours of Kryptonite and the effects on the Man of Steel. I remember this because I'd bought it at lunchtime but England were playing West Germany that afternoon in the World Cup final. Therefore it was halftime before I looked at it.